# Install4j handle Cancel event for multiple screens

Tags: java, handler, install4j

So I would like to create a custom dialog that shows up if a user cancels the install after a certain section of the installer. Is there a way to do something like this. I have several Progress screens and Configurable Forms after the Install screen. If they proceed after the install portion I would like to warn them with an additional message of information specific to my product. Any suggestions on making some global handler?

I am aware of the context.isCancelling() however i'm not sure where to use this or even a place to handle the cancel event. The installer is run as GUI 99% of the time so the "Console Screen Change Handler" won't work for me (but I would love something similar).

Any suggestions are welcome!!! Thank you so much STACKOVERFLOW!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an InstallerEventListener.

Add a "Run script" action to your "Startup" node with following code:

```
context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
   public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent installerEvent) {
        if (installerEvent.getType() == EventType.CANCELLING) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
});
return true;
```